# Named Constructor Idiom in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Is using the Named Constructor Idiom possible in VB.NET? I've found many examples in C#/C++ but can't quite wrap my head around how to use it in vb.net. Seems like a better method of keeping my code readable when involving a lot of constructors with similar argument types.

Comment: Clumsy name, google "vb.net factory pattern" for relevant hits.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard this term before, but after a quick search it sounds vaguely like the Static Factory Pattern.  The idea is you make the constructor private and use a shared (static in c#) public function to create the new object.

```
Public Class Foo

Private Sub New()
    
End Sub

Public Shared Function CreateNew(param as Object) as Foo
    Dim obj as New Foo()
    obj.Prop = param
    return obj
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: The change in 'name description' explains why I could find no references to it for vb.net. Thanks for the concise example, that is what I was looking to implement to 'clean up' my constructors with similiar arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You sure can make Named Constructors in VB.  The pattern uses a static (Shared in VB) factory method on the class itself, so that the method can be named.  (Other Factory patterns involve using a separate Factory class to provide the static method.)

System.Drawing.Color is a simple example.  The pattern is implemented underneath as a static (Shared) property.  Since no arguments are necessary, the Get method of a Property works just fine:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property Chartreuse As Color
```

Usage:

```
Dim favoriteColor as Color = Color.Chartreuse
```

Or you can make static factory methods to do the same thing.

```
Public Class TheClass
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(input As String)
        'do something with input
    End Sub
    Public Shared Function MyNamedConstructor() As TheClass
        Return New TheClass
    End Function
    Public Shared Function AnotherNamedConstructor() As TheClass
        Return New TheClass("Another Name")
    End Function
End Class
```

As for whether this pattern is "better" than overloading constructors, that's really an opinion.  Personally, I would just overload the constructors.  As you can see in the example above, the constructors need to be there anyway.

I suggest using the Named Constructor pattern when you have only a few possible ways to construct your class/struct, but consumers of your class/struct will be using those few constructors often, and with different input values to those constructors (as in the System.Drawing.Color example).

The Name in 'Named Constructor' doesn't represent a name for the constructor itself, but for the object resulting from the constructor.  If your named constructor can be used to create two objects that don't feel right to give the same name to, then don't give the constructor that name.